# XMing Get Full Screen of Linux Remotely

Tags: linux, windows

I was wondering how I would go about getting the sort of full screen image of a desktop running linux from windows using xming. Basically, I dont just want the console.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the xdcmp directions on the xming web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into some VNC software.  There is a free edition of [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/download.html) that is worth checking out.

Some Linux distros may ship with VNC software already, so poke around on your machine first.

Answer (score 0):

I also have never tried it myself, but seen many a person on the tubez rant and rave for [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/), which is the GPLed code that is the core of their commercial product.  The claim on their homepage:

> NX is an exciting new technology for
>   remote display. It provides near local
>   speed application responsiveness over
>   high latency, low bandwidth links. The
>   core libraries for NX are provided by
>   NoMachine under the GPL. FreeNX is a
>   GPL implementation of the NX Server
>   and NX Client Components.

They also [have a Windows client](http://www.nomachine.com/download-client-windows.php), which I was unaware of until some Googling.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, look at the previous solutions but also look at,
http://ulteo.com/home/
If you're curious I've had decent performance while running VNC via a web browser.